# Autolayout is broken when UILabel given trailing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

It works fine if I don't give trailing properties.
However, if the text is long, it will be cut off the screen.

[image]
[image]

---

So I set trailing.
But, this will break the width of the UICollectionViewCell.

[image]
[image]

---

This is my code

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: width / 2, height: 53)
}
```

Why is that? Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect by setting trailing? Imaging case when text is bigger than your specified width. What do you want it to look like in this case?

Comment: Also, you need to subtract from width/2 the `(contentInsets.left + contentInsets.right) + (sectionInsets.left + sectionInsets.right) + minimumInteritemSpacing`

Comment: I believe you want it to go to second line in case if the text becomes bigger. So edit your trailing constraint and change = to >=.  Also set `Lines` property of your label to something bigger than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method is just set label lines as **0**

[image]

@oddK - Don't set the width as collection width / 2, instead set the width based on the text content,

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let lblWidth = "My text".getWidth(withConstrainedHeight: CGFloat(53), font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14))

        return CGSize(width: lblWidth, height: 53)
    }



    //Get Width of content in label
        func getWidth(withConstrainedHeight:CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
            let viewRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: withConstrainedHeight)
            let getFrame = self.boundingRect(with: viewRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], context: nil)
            return getFrame.size.width
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I need to make a cell that is 1/2 the size of a width.

Comment: @oddK - Then use the adjust size option for label

Comment: @oddK - Did you tried the automatically adjust font size option. Find the attachment i have shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209907/discussion-between-kannan-t-and-oddk).

Comment: solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755978/uicollectionviewcell-is-wrong-width-with-label?noredirect=1#comment107493970_60755978