# UICollectionViewCell is wrong width with label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I found something strange.
I created a custom UICollectionViewCell and a label inside it.
I applied auto-layout only to the top, leading, and bottom of the label.

[image]

```swift
class TestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

And if the text is long, it is clipped off the screen like below.

[image]

I want the text to be displayed as just "..." if it is too long.
So I applied traling auto-layout like this.

[image]

Then, collectionViewCell width is broke.

[image]

This is my code.
I already set delegate, datasource.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TestCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        cell.label.text = "asdfasdkfjabsdkljfbasdfhaoweihf;oaisefowiejfao;wihfaksdjfhakdjf;lskdjfa;zxknb"
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - 1) / 2, height: 53)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting estimate size for cell from collectionview to none ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UICollectionViewLayout Not working with UIImage in Swift 5 and Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181037/uicollectionviewlayout-not-working-with-uiimage-in-swift-5-and-xcode-11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `Storyboard` and select your `CollectionView`.
Now open Size inspector and change **Estimated size** `Automatic` to `None`.

[image]

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating size of cell as:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 1) / 2, height: 53)
}
```

Comment: No, exactly same result my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the cell using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - 1) / 2, height: 53)
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
}
```

[image: Discription]